# How to use menu and onKeyDown() on the same activity

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app. I have written my own code for back key event.
For that i am catching events using this method 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) .....

I also want to use Menu options I have used Inflator for that.
But when I click on menu button, that event caught by my onKeyDown method.

I am not expecting that, I expect to execute following methods,

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){ // creating menu using MenuInflator }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case :
            return true;
        default:

        }
    }
```

How could I use both the things on the same activity?? Any Idea ???

Comment: Hi ....... Thanks for your quick response. But I got the answer. I need to return false in onkeydown() so that uncatched key events could handled outside.

Comment: OK, In that case, please edit the question with the fix so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) of `onKeyDown()`:

- it is normal that it receives the 'menu button pressed' event, as any `KeyEvent`
- but if you return `false`, this event will continue to be propagated and will therefore lead `onOptionsItemSelected()` to be called

So you should code your `onKeyDown()` in a way that lets the `KeyEvent` to propagate if you do not handle it on your own.

In the following example, we have two keys that are interesting to us: one we fully handle on our own, one we just track, and we ignore all the rest:

```
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean handled = false; // By default we let the event propagation turned on

    if (keyCode == A_KEY_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_HANDLE_BY_YOURSELF) {
        doSomething();
        handled = true; // Stops the event propagation
    }
    else if (keyCode == A_KEY_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_TRACK_WITHOUT_PREVENTING_THE_SYSTEM_FROM_HANDLING_IT) {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
    // else, you neither handle or track that key

    return handled;
 }
```